# Spring boot: ReentrantLock

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, synchronization, distributed-computing

I've coded a `@Repository` class:

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryDocumentDao {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RepositoryDocumentDao.class);
    private ReentrantLock lock;

    @Autowired
    public RepositoryDocumentDao(
    ) {
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }
}
```

My related code is:

```
private boolean verifyStorageSize(long requiredBytes) {
    this.lock.lock();
    LOG.debug("IN");
    //.. do someting large
    LOG.debug("OUT");
    this.lock.unlock();
}
```

I've took a look on logs and two threads has entered inside protected code:

```
http-nio-8080-exec-3 =================IN=================  
...
http-nio-8080-exec-10 =================IN=================
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Either they're not using the same lock, or they're not acquiring the lock at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean with "at the same time"?

Comment: Well a lock is mutually exclusive, so if you're claiming that two threads acquired the same lock, it couldn't have happened at the same time (unless `ReentrantLock` is fundamentally broken, which it isn't). So you have 2 choices: multiple locks or misreading of the log messages. I'm surprised you're using `ReentrantLock` in a repository anyway, sounds suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

***I couldn't reproduce the case what you mentioned***, but I made you a simple example how I implemented the code.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/event")
    public class EventRestController extends BaseRestController {

        private final EventService service;

        @Autowired
        public EventRestController(final EventService service) {
            this.service = requireNonNull(service, "service can't be null");
        }

        @PutMapping(value = "/sync")
        public Callable<ResponseEntity<Void>> syncOperation() {
            return () -> service.syncOperation();
        }
    ...
    }

    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {

        private final EventRepository repository;
        private final ReentrantLock fairLock;

        @Autowired
        public EventServiceImpl(@Qualifier("eventRepository") final EventRepository repository) {
            this.repository = requireNonNull(repository, "repository can't be null");
            this.fairLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void syncOperation() {
            log.debug("thread try to acquire lock");
            boolean isLockAcquired = false;
            try {
               isLockAcquired = fairLock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            if (isLockAcquired) {
               try {
                  log.debug("{} own the lock", Thread.currentThread().getName());
                  // heavy operation
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  throw new IllegalStateException(e);
               } finally {
                  fairLock.unlock();
                  log.debug("thread unlock");
               }
           }

           log.debug("thread - {} end of method", Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }
    ...
}
```

Bash code what invoke endpoint:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX=$1

for (( c=1; c<=MAX; c++ ))
do
   curl -X PUT http://localhost:2000/app/event/sync > /dev/null 2>&1 &
done
```

Invocation:

```
./sync.sh 5
```

It will start 5 process in background and 5 concurrent process will invoke the endpoint.

Log messages:

```
15:59:22.026 [task-1] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread try to aquire lock
15:59:22.026 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread try to aquire lock
15:59:22.026 [task-3] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread try to aquire lock
15:59:22.026 [task-5] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread try to aquire lock
15:59:22.026 [task-4] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread try to aquire lock
15:59:22.026 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-2 own the lock
15:59:24.027 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread unlock
15:59:24.027 [task-3] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-3 own the lock
15:59:24.027 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread - task-2 end of method
15:59:26.027 [task-3] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread unlock
15:59:26.028 [task-3] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread - task-3 end of method
15:59:26.028 [task-1] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-1 own the lock
15:59:28.029 [task-1] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread unlock
15:59:28.029 [task-5] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-5 own the lock
15:59:28.029 [task-1] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread - task-1 end of method
```

In the example we can see that ***task-2*** thread successfully get the lock and the other threads try to get lock and they are blocked until ***task-2*** release the lock, and ***thread-4*** didn't get the lock in appropriate time.

I think this part is interesting:

```
15:59:22.026 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-2 own the lock
15:59:24.027 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread unlock
15:59:24.027 [task-3] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - task-3 own the lock
15:59:24.027 [task-2] DEBUG hu.gaszabo.persistence.app.application.EventServiceImpl - thread - task-2 end of method
```

***task-2*** thread got the lock, 2 seconds later it released the lock, ***task-3*** thread immediately got the lock before ***task-2*** thread wroted 'end of method' message.

***The answer of your question can be that some operations are happening in the same time (It would be better to see timestamps), but it shows you in order in the log what you can misunderstand (for example, what I showed represents this situation).***